# New login is created but 'sa' cant assign grant/deny permissions to user in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I created users with login option in security tab in SQL Server 2008 R2 running on windows 7 successfully and grant permissions to :

```
Use dummydb
Grant REFERENCES  ON OBJECT::vuUser TO nvp
GO

Use dummydb
Deny INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE ON OBJECT::dummyDB.userTb to nvp
GO
```

nvp user can login successfully and restriction work great but when I create user and grant permissions as above on SQL Server 2008 R2 running on windows server 2008.

User can login successfully but when I try to grant permission using above code, I get this message:

> *Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Cannot find the object 'usertb', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

Is their is something I am doing wrong or I need to try something else ?????

Database and table name are correct...

I login in using user 'sa' credentials

Need urgent help n thanks in advance

Comment: See if SA is the database owner under the Database , Properties, Files tab

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is OBJECT::Schema.Table **not** OBJECT::Database.Table

e.g.

```
use test
Deny INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.T1 to public
```

Answer (score 0):

Greeting Madi,

Being that you're pressed on time here is a helpful video link that you can use as a sanity check..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh5USR7pymE

If you still have issues please provide step and error if available.

Regards,
Jav

Comment: Please provide a succinct text based answer to the question in addition to the 10min video.

Comment: I can't view the video as it is blocked in pkistan :(